# Is it possible to customize/seed the Hyperledger Composer Playground?

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hashtag, hyperledger, hyperledger-composer

I have the playground running on a virtual machine which is connected to hyperledger fabric (a bunch of docker containers).

When a user visits the playground the page is more or less empty by default. I've been able to issue ID cards which makes it possible for others to see and interact with my network.

However, is it possible to customize the playground landing page with some restrictions? In particular I'd like to a particular network (as public?) and restrict making new networks.

I.e. I want to use the playground to showcase my network, not showcase the Hyperledger Playground itself!

Answer (score 1):

No, I don't believe it is possible to do this today. You should file an issue (with the enhancement tag) and describe the requirements. Pull requests accepted! :-)

Comment: Does the release last night change anything? In particular #2281
https://github.com/hyperledger/composer/releases/tag/v0.14.0
https://github.com/hyperledger/composer/pull/2281

Answer (score 0):

imo, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45085949/modifying-hyperledger-composer-webapp) might just be the solution you are looking for.

Although, I've not completely gone through the reference mentioned above, as I don't know much about AngularJS explained in there. But it is relevant to this one. should be of help.

Please correct me if I'm wrong though!

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.